# Первый элемент с классом

Tags: javascript, jquery

Подскажите, где ошибся

```
$('#messages').first({
    $(this).css('background', 'grey');
})
```

Comment: ошибка в синтаксисе. Что за функция first? Посмотри в справке какие параметры она принимает, и что ей передаешь ты?

Answer (score 7):

1. неверный синтаксис

   ```
   {
       $(this).css('background','grey');
   }
   ```

   так писать нельзя. Если нужно передать объект с полями, нужно указать эти поля, если нужно передать результат `$(this).css('background','grey')` надо и передавать результат
2. функция [.first](https://api.jquery.com/first/) - **НЕ ПРИНИМАЕТ** аргументов, поэтому код можно было сократить до `$('#messages').first()`
3. ошибочное предположение, что селектор по id: `$('#messages')` может вернуть больше одного элемента
4. для выставления css-стиля нужно использовать `.css` метод.

В итоге код должен принять вид: `$('#messages').css('background','grey');`

Comment: Насчет 4го пункта - так автор и пытается использовать `.css` метод. Только очень криво (это уже остальные 3 пункта).

Comment: @Regent, наверное я имел ввиду, что css прямо к выборке надо применять :-)

Comment: решил, спасибо Вам  
 $('#messages:first')
  .css('border', '3px solid red');

Comment: @Aslero, перечитай третий пункт. `first` - не нужен, потому что у тебя в наборе **всегда** один элемент

Comment: а почему этот скрипт выполняется только, если я еще раз нажму f5 ?

Comment: @Aslero, какой скрипт? а когда он должен выполняться?

Comment: <script>
 
  $('#messages').addClass('mess');
 
</script>

Comment: после загрузки страницы

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61775/discussion-between-grundy-and-aslero).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте этот код:

```
$('#messages').first().css('background', 'grey');
```